# How to find out original github page for any custom domain?

Tags: github-pages

Suppose i hosted my static site content on github page and then added CNAME and created a cusom domain www.xyz.com . How can I find in which github page is my site hosted by only looking up www.xyz.com .(If it is possible.)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I just wanted to know if anyone was able to find my original place where my site was hosted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i  found it out myself. Do a DNS lookup and the canonical name is the original github page source.